# How can I Prove the following Integral Inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to prove the following inequality:

$$\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\Big(\int \big|f(x)\big|\big|g(x-k)\big|dx\Big)^2 \leq \big\|f\big\|^2 \sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\Big (\int\big|g(x-k)\big|dx\Big)^2$$
where

$$\|f\|^2=\int |f(x)|^2dx.$$

**My attempt**: Just prove the following inequality

$$\Big(\int \big|f(x)\big|\big|g(x-k)\big|dx\Big)^2 \leq \|f\|^2\Big(\int \big|g(x-k)\big|dx\Big)^2$$
I think that this inequality is different from the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.
Cauchy–Schwarz inequality is 
$$\Big|\int f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx\Big|^2 \leq \int |f(x)|^2dx ~\cdot~\int |g(x)|^2dx $$

Comment: What is your definition of $\| f\|$ and what have you tried?

Comment: This seems like a direct consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz.